# Geodesics in upper half-plane model of $\mathbb{H}$

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

On [this](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~schlag/bookweb.pdf#page=20) page in Schlag's book on complex analysis, he is discussing the upper half-plane model of $\mathbb{H}^2$. He says

> for all $z_0\in \mathbb{H}$ $$\{T'(z_0) \mid T \in PSL(2, \mathbb{R})
>  \cap \text{Stab}(z_0)\} = SO(2,\mathbb{R}),$$ which means that the
>   stabilizer subgroup in $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ at any point $z_0$ in the
>   upper half-plane acts on the tangent space at $z_0$ by arbitrary
>   rotations. Therefore, the geodesics of $\mathbb{H}$ are all circles
>   that intersect the real line at a right angle.

I understand both of these facts in isolation, but could someone explain to me why the first fact implies the second? Thanks

Comment: I imagine you start somewhere; rays with constant real part, as $A + i e^t,$ are unit speed geodesics.

Comment: @WillJagy Sorry, I'm not sure what you're saying. I understand the normal proof that the geodesics are these circles, starting with the fact that vertical lines are geodesics, and then proceeding through a Mobius transformation. What does this have to do with the derivatives of the stabilizer being $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a fact in Riemannian geometry that (oriented) geodesics through a given point are determined by the tangent vector it makes at that point. Thus, in particular, given any point in the hyperbolic plane, the vertical line through it is the unique geodesic with vertical tangent vector.

Now, given any other geodesic through a point, one may apply a rotation from the point-stabilizer to make a new geodesic whose tangent line is vertical - this must be the vertical line. As such, any geodesic is the image of a vertical line under a Mobius transformations, which are vertical lines and semicircles. Since the vertical line intersects the real axis at a right angle and hyperbolic isometries are conformal, all the semicircles must intersect the real axis at right angles.